# Does ASP.NET worker process still return data in chunks of 31kb

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, .net-4.0

Does ASP.NET worker process still return data in chunks of  31Kb

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx) written in May 2004 specifies the following.

> When using the ASP.NET process model,
>   the ASP.NET worker process sends
>   responses back to the client, it first
>   sends them through IIS in 31-kilobyte
>   (KB) chunks. This applies to .NET
>   Framework 1.1, but it could change in
>   future versions. The more 31-KB chunks
>   that ASP.NET has to send through IIS,
>   the slower your page runs. You can
>   determine how many chunks ASP.NET
>   requires for your page by browsing the
>   page, viewing the source, and then
>   saving the file to disk. To determine
>   the number of chunks, divide the page
>   size by 31.

Has this architecture been changed since 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0?
 
If so then whats the new chunk size for each of the new versions of .NET?

[Edit]
Its been more than two weeks since the posting still no `correct` reply :(
And please do not provide speculative answers

Comment: SO recommends a bounty if your question is unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/faq  `If, after 2 days, you still don't have an answer you like, you can offer a bounty`

Comment: Why did you turned it into a community wiki? now no-one will answer your question :(

Comment: BTW, from my personal experience with SO bounties - I would not recommend it.

Comment: have u tried sending an email to Scott Hanselman or Phil haack.
(or ScottGu for that matter)

Comment: @vivek, thanx. mailed computerzen, never thought this question would take this long to answer.

Comment: @Eran - why is that?  It seems that questions with bounties get a lot more traffic/answers.  BTW - why is this a community wiki?  I know a lot of people don't answer CW questions since they don't get reputation for those answers.

Comment: @Andrew - It's true, but it also means that your question will expire in a week. Which can be very unfortunate if the correct answer will not be supplied (happened to me twice).

Comment: Same reason I am not keeping a bounty..

Answer (score 2):

I think the real question is - does it matter?  The original article was horribly written to make you think that it does.  The 31kb chunks returned from the worker process to IIS are all on one system, it did not mean that 31kb chunks are returned to the client.  IIS processes those chunks then separately determines how to chunk them to send to the client.  Performance is not related to the # of chunks, it's related to the # of bytes.

Changing the size of the chunks would not change your performance in any appreciable way.  It would be like trying to change the internal memory page size on a word document.  I think this is the reason MS hasn't mentioned the chunk size since 2004 - it's an internal measure that has no appreciable bearing on performance.

Comment: @andrew there has been 3 answers prior to yours which were deleted, please please put this as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @Binoj - you're asking something that is internal to Microsoft software, not something that has anything to do with performance.  You won't get an answer by asking people to delete their answers ... add a bounty.

Comment: but the fact remains that your answer is still a comment on the question and not an answer. 
If this question remain unanswered then there was some chance that someone from MS would have a look at this, you are spoiling this opportunity. Anyways I have no control on moderating non-answers :(
My intention was to keep it in the unanswered questions for at least some time till it gets answered...

Comment: Binoj - it only remains on the unanswered question list for a short period of time as well.  Add a bounty.